# Are there any polls explicitly measuring "impeachment fatigue"?

Tags: united-states, public-opinion, trump-impeachment

There are at least a couple of articles ([NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/12/16/us/politics/on-politics-impeachment-outcome.html), [The Hill](https://thehill.com/opinion/white-house/470947-3-reasons-why-impeachment-fatigue-has-already-set-in)) that talk of "impeachment fatigue" among the US public already. In one [PBS piece/interview](https://www.pbs.org/newshour/show/what-voters-across-america-are-saying-about-impeachment) it was it even claimed explicitly that this fatigue affects independent voters in particular:

> Then I checked in with another independent voter. We have a lot of them here. And that independent voter said they're at complete fatigue. They're done. They're not watching. They want to move on to issues. We are an issue-oriented populace here.

Are there any polls that measure this "impeachment fatigue" sentiment *explicitly and systematically* though, i.e. not by trying to divine it from the approval ratings of the impeachment process (or just using anecdotal evidence from a handful of voters)?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the populace is issue-oriented.